# How to use length of an array in subtraction

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

My code below is working perfect when I write number or only len inside of it. However, I want to write(len-3) but it again return as if I write len inside of it. How can I solve it??
I get the length of the array by using:

```
int len = sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]);
```

The message variable is a String and received is:

```
char received = Serial.read();


    if (Index<(len-3)){
       message=tmp[Index++]=received;
       Serial.print(message);
                    }
```

My aim is when I write dv35!1234567890*asdfqwertyuiopmnbvcx#asdas the code should return the part of it that is between '!' and '#' then during the if else part the code should get some parts of it. However, the last part should return until 3 chars before the array ends. but it did not work properly. it returns all the parts remaining.(As if I write only len inside of it). the length of the input is not stable so the message part changes depending on the length of the whole array. It should return 3 chars before the end.
Here is my whole code:

```
char tmp[200] = {0};
String pack;
String command;
String Size;
String messum;
String message;
String checksum;
int len = sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]);
int Index = 0;
bool Seen = false;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){  
    while (Serial.available() > 0){
        char received = Serial.read();
        if (received == '!'){
            Seen = true;
        }
        else if (received == '#'){
            return strdup(tmp);


        }
        else if (Seen == true){ 
            if(Index<2){
              //Serial.print("P");
              pack=tmp[Index++] = received;
              Serial.print(pack);
               }
             else if(Index<4){
              //Serial.print("C");
              command=tmp[Index++] = received;
              Serial.print(command);
               }
             else if(Index<6){
              //Serial.print("S");
              Size=tmp[Index++] = received;
              Serial.print(Size);

              }
              else if (Index<(len-3)){
               Serial.print("M");
               message=tmp[Index++]=received;
               Serial.print(message);
                }
             }
    }
    return NULL;
    //input:  dv35!1234567890*asdfqwertyuiopmnbvcx#asdas
}
```

Comment: if `tmp` is an argument of a function, then your length calculation will fail because the size is not known inside the function. So please show us more of your code.

Comment: Ok I will show. But when I paste all of my code people say use minimalist questions etc. anyway I will edit my question

Comment: I added my whole code sir @PaulOgilvie

Comment: `return strdup(tmp);` `return NULL;` are invalid - `loop` returns `void`. `working perfect when I write number or only len inside of it` - what does it mean "working perfect"? What happens when something "woks perfect"? What "numbers" do you write exactly? What "len" (the string `"len"` or some length?) do you write exactly? Please post: what does the execution of your code produce? what happens when you execute the code in which circumstances? what does not happen? what did you expect to happen? what you want to happen?

Comment: But when the code sees # it should return for example if my input is !dalsjdadlk#jskd then after # should not be added to the array

Comment: `I want to write(len-3) but it again return as if I write len inside of it.` I do not understand that sentence. You want to write the string `"len-3"`? Where do you want to "write" it? Do you want to write a count of `len-3` characters? `return as if I write len` where do you write `len`? What is exactly "returned" and from where? `inside of it` what is `it`? There is no `write()` function in the code you posted that takes `len-3` or `len` as argument..

Comment: What is the expected output and actual output for the sample input?

Comment: I edited my code again @aschepler

Comment: That input does not look 197 characters long.

Comment: so what should I write inside the tmp[]? because the length of it depends on the input

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of most of it.

1. You define the variable `tmp` in the global and it has constant length. You do not need to calculate the length of it.
2. For the `char` array `sizeof(char_array)` gives you the length of the array as `sizeof(char)` is by definition **`1`**
3. Use the correct types. for the sizes use `size_t` not `int`

Comment: but the length of the tmp depends on the input

Comment: not it does not: `char tmp[200] = {0};` It is always `200`

Comment: Ok then what should I write inside of the tmp[]?

Comment: Do I have to use malloc?

Comment: I know then do you have a suggestion to use dynamic memory allocation in my code?

Comment: can I implement something like this? : `for(int i=0; i<len;i++){
  if(tmp[i]==NULL){
    remove tmp[i]
    len--;
 }
}  `     here remove means remove that part not about the code